# Making Git, Gitweb and Gitolite work on Debian Wheezy

Tags: git, apache, debian, gitolite, gitweb

I've run into a problem when trying to install Git, Gitweb and Gitolite together on my server. Basically I can get Git and either Gitweb or Gitolite working no problem, but as soon as I add the missing program, it doesn't work.

If I install Git and Gitolite first, Gitweb reports that no projects exist, even after pointing gitweb.conf to where my repositories are located (/home/git/repositories/)

If I install Git and GitWeb first, my gitolite-admin repository shows up in the gitweb list along with all the SSH keys.

After scouring Google for a good few hours and reading some pretty crazy suggestions including changing the user that runs the Apache web server. I'm still no closer to getting it to work.

This is what I've tried up until this point. (And in this order)

- Installed git and apache using apt-get.
- Created a 'git' user with the home directory of /home/git
- Cloned Gitolite from the official repo (Apparently the one via apt-get is 'old'?) and set it up as directed [here.](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/install.html#qi)

  - At this point testing.git and gitolite-admin.git are in /home/git/repositories/
- Installed gitweb via apt-get and modified /etc/gitweb.conf like so:

  ```
  $projectroot = "/home/git/repositories";
  ```

After restarting Apache, no repositories are listed.

I've also tried:

- Adding the git user to the www-data group. No apparent change.
- Trying to install gitolite into /var/cache/git, but then I can't clone anything. (404 error)
- Changing the umask variable to 0027 (I honestly don't understand this, but I've seen it in numerous Google results.)
- Changing permissions on /home/git to 777 (Terrible idea, I know. But this still didn't show any repositories.)

My final goal is just to get this three things working together, but it's proving more difficult that I originally imagined.

Where am I going wrong?